# setting up perl packages in a different dir

Tags: perl

I am looking into rewriting a old application in Perl.

Setting up three packages and running subroutines from them makes a lot of sense for what I'm going to be doing, but I'm not very familiar with setting up packages.

I want the packages to be in the same place as my other Perl scripts, i.e. nothing other than scripts in this bin directory will need to call these packages.

My question is how can I point Perl to know where my packages are (and how do I install them in a place other then the default) and is this an okay/smart thing to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common task.  The PERL5LIB environment variable contains a list of directories to look for a module in.  You can also use the the [`lib` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) to specify directories a specific script should look for module in:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use lib "$ENV{HOME}/lib";
```

You might also want to look into [`cpanm`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/lib/App/cpanminus.pm) and [`local::lib`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/local-lib/lib/local/lib.pm).

Answer (score 2):

If the packages and scripts are in the same location, I'd recommend using [`FindBin`](https://metacpan.org/module/FindBin):

```
use FindBin '$Bin';
use lib $Bin;
```

Comment: If they are in the same location, isn't the path already included?

Comment: `FindBin` isn't deprecated as such, but it does things in a very obscure way and is prone to breaking, [as decribed here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=41213). I think [scriptname](https://metacpan.org/module/scriptname) is a better bet.

Comment: @DimitarPetrov : Not necessarily. `@INC` includes the present working directory (`.`), not the directory where the script exists. The two are only the same if the script is contained in the current working directory.

Comment: @Borodin : Thanks for the heads-up, although the link you provided alludes to some bug being fixed now.